# Component in react doesn't render when in .map() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been learning react and redux to develop a web application (Using egghead.io courses from Dan and Joe) and there's something I can't seem to get working even after watching the courses multiple times

I'm basically trying to render an array of items using .map() function and nothing get's rendered, I map through the array right after to check if the re-rendering is being triggered with the right state and it is. Here's the code in question:

```
{TaskManagerStore.getState().tasks.map(task =>
    <Task key={task.id} task={task} />
)}
{TaskManagerStore.getState().tasks.map( task =>
    console.log(task)
)}

<AddTaskButton onClick={() => (
    TaskManagerStore.dispatch({
        type: 'ADD_TASK',
        title: 'Test task',
        content: 'Hey there!',
        id: testID++
    })
)}/>
```

The console log prints all items in the array (first nothing, then 0, then [0, 1], etc) but the  component is not being rendered. I've put a console log inside the component's render method and it never gets called

How can the console.log be working in the .map() but not be rendering the component?

EDIT: Full TaskManager component: https://gist.github.com/Kylar13/6e9b58852f22b64fe5281ed905bf2bc4

EDIT 2: Task component:

```
const Task = ({ task }) => {

    return (
        <div className="Task">
            <h3 className="Task-title">{task.title}</h3>
            <p className="Task-content">{task.content}</p>
            <div className="Task-editButton">Edit<i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"/></div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: can you post your complete render method?

Comment: Here you go https://gist.github.com/Kylar13/6e9b58852f22b64fe5281ed905bf2bc4

Will add it to the question as well

Comment: Remember that Array.map() returns a *new* array with all of the result of the callback function. If your map function is running but not rendering anything, I'm guessing that it's not within the return (...) portion of your render function

Comment: @StandardQuality  According to what I've seen, the way I've written it should implicitly return the <Task /> component

Comment: @kylar13 you're right, i had typed that before I saw your gist. Have you tried inspecting your app with the React extension for Chrome Dev tools? It will let you see what the state and props are for each component.
Also, it seems odd to be calling the .getState() method within your render function - I'd expect that you would use the store to update the state from within a lifecycle hook. (But, if they're doing this in the tutorial, they're smarter than I am, I'd trust it)

Comment: can you show Task component also?

Comment: @StandardQuality they later refactor it in the tutorial and explain why you shouldn't do it, but I first wanted to get it to work without doing the way you'd do it in production

Comment: @MayankShukla Added it to the post!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to call Task as a function, e.g.:

```
const Task = ({ task }) => {

    return (
        <div key={task.id} className="Task">
            <h3 className="Task-title">{task.title}</h3>
            <p className="Task-content">{task.content}</p>
            <div className="Task-editButton">Edit<i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"/></div>
        </div>
    )
};

{TaskManagerStore.getState().tasks.map(task => Task({ task })}
```

Comment: React complains about the child in the array iterator not having a key when I directly call the function. "Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: then try to add it inside the Task function

Comment: Inside the Task function doesn't work, the component rendered in the map() function is the one that needs to have the "key" prop:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: docs also says you have to wrap it with a separate container (div), like: <div>{TaskManagerStore.getState().tasks.map(task =>
    <Task key={task.id} task={task} />
)}</div>

Comment: It's already inside of a div in the full code linked in the first edit, apologies for not making that clear in the snipped

Comment: yes, I saw it in the gist but I meant crating a <div> and putting only this component inside and no siblings

Answer (score 0):

In your Task component you're passing two props, key and task. I solved the issue by adding an additional prop that refers directly to the state tree, like this...

```
const tasks = TaskManagerStore.getState().tasks

{tasks.map(task =>
    <Task 
      key={task.id} 
      task={task} 
      tasks={tasks}/>
)}
```

It's certainly not an elegant solution, but for some reason I can't get the components generated by the .map() function to re-render without referencing the state directly. If anyone has insight on why this is I'd love to hear it!